# How does one grab an attachment ID of file types that are not images?

Tags: wordpress, attachment

I've found a terrific number of tutorials/code examples which provide you with the code to grab and echo the attachment ID of an image, but not a single one which works with anything else, such as Zip and Rar archives - which is precisely what I've working with.

Would anyone know how to go about grabbing and echoing the ID of a file (in this case, a Zip archive) from within WordPress `attachment.php` page? Oddly enough, grabbing the ID of a Zip archive appears simple when attempted via `single.php`, but I'm really struggling to nail this from within `attachment.php`.

Really can't understand why WordPress has a built-in `get_post_thumbnail_id();` for images, but nothing available for any other type of file.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the example [*Show All attachments for the current post beside Thumb*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id#Show_All_attachments_for_the_current_post_beside_Thumb) on (ironically, given your comments!) the [`get_post_thumbnail_id()` codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id).

Basically you set up a `get_posts()` query for *all* attachments.  You'd then just need to filter your results on file type extension, or if you know it (and it's recorded correctly), the `WP_Post.post_mime_type` using [`get_post_mime_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_mime_type).

(The example filters out the featured image/thumb too... But your filter would take care of that anyhow).

But if you can use the MIME type as a filter, you can set up the `get_posts()` args with a `'post_mime_types'` argument, to only return attachments of one (or more) specific MIME type(s). You'd probably want to take a peek at the attachments' underlying database entries to check how this is recorded so that you can properly match against it. I expect your .zip files are `application/zip`, but I'd double check before relying on that.

So, something like:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'application/zip'
    );

$attachments = get_posts( $args );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding, Sepster. I managed to find the embarrassingly simple answer by scouring through one of the TwentyTwelve theme's files; turns out the answer is as simple as echoing...

```
<?php the_ID(); ?>
```

...inside the attachment.php file.